# MyISAM key buffer

Tags: mysql, myisam

Good evening,

I want to know how can I use informations about MyISAM to calculate :

- size of buffer,
- size of buffer used,
- Write ratio,
- Read ratio,
- and MyISAM key cache hit rate

and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Key Buffer Size

```
SELECT variable_value INTO @KBS
FROM information_schema.global_variables WHERE variable_name='key_buffer_size';
SELECT @KBS KeyBufferSize;
```

This should be the same number as

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'key_buffer_size';
```

## Key Buffer in Use

```
SELECT variable_value INTO @KBUSED
FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name='Key_blocks_used';
SELECT variable_value INTO @KCBSIZ
FROM information_schema.global_variables WHERE variable_name='key_cache_block_size';
SET @KBINUSE = @KBUSED * @KCBSIZ;
SELECT @KBUSED KeyBlocksUsed,@KCBSIZ KeyCacheBlockSize,@KBINUSE KeyBlocksInUse;
```

### Key Read and Write Ratios, Query Cache HitRate (based on `@SECONDS_TO_TEST`)

```
SET @SECONDS_TO_TEST = 30;
SELECT variable_value INTO @KRDS1
FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name='Key_reads';
SELECT variable_value INTO @KRQS1
FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name='Key_read_requests';
SELECT variable_value INTO @KWRT1
FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name='Key_writes';
SELECT variable_value INTO @KWRQ1
FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name='Key_write_requests';
SELECT variable_value INTO @QCHITS1
FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name='Qcache_hits';
SELECT variable_value INTO @QCNSRT1
FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name='Qcache_inserts';
SELECT variable_value INTO @QCNC1
FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name='Qcache_not_cached';
SELECT SLEEP(@SECONDS_TO_TEST);
SELECT variable_value INTO @KRDS2
FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name='Key_reads';
SELECT variable_value INTO @KRQS2
FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name='Key_read_requests';
SELECT variable_value INTO @KWRT2
FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name='Key_writes';
SELECT variable_value INTO @KWRQ2
FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name='Key_write_requests';
SELECT variable_value INTO @QCHITS2
FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name='Qcache_hits';
SELECT variable_value INTO @QCNSRT2
FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name='Qcache_inserts';
SELECT variable_value INTO @QCNC2
FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name='Qcache_not_cached';
SET @KRQS = @KRQS2 - @KRQS1; SET @KRDS = @KRDS2 - @KRDS1;
SET @KRR = 100 - ((100 * @KRDS) / @KRQS);
SET @KWRT = @KWRT2 - @KWRT1; SET @KWRQ = @KWRQ2 - @KWRQ1;
SET @KWR = 100 - ((100 * @KWRT) / @KWRQ);
SET @QCHITS = @QCHITS2 - @QCHITS1; SET @QCNSRT = @QCNSRT2 - @QCNSRT1;
SET @QCNC = @QCNC2 - @QCNC1; SET @QCHR = 100 * @QCHITS / (@QCHITS + @QCNSRT + @QCNC);
SELECT @KRDS KeyReads,@KRQS KeyReadRequests,IFNULL(@KRR,100) KeyReadRatio,
    @KWRT KeyWrites,@KWRQ KeyWriteRequests,IFNULL(@KWR,100) KeyWriteRatio,
    @QCHITS QueryCacheHits,@QCNSRT QueryCacheInserts,@QCNC QueryCacheNotCached,
    IFNULL(@QCHR,0) QueryCacheHitRate;
```

Comment: Thank you :D
have you an article about using informations about Innodb, query cache for calculate some statistics

Comment: The book <a href=http://www.amazon.com/Database-Design-Tuning-Robert-Schneider/dp/0672327651>MySQL Database and Tuning</a>  has a good tuning and monitoring guide for InnoDB on pages 265-279, naming all the status variables you need to monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Ronaldo anwser is very helpful, but you have to change

```
SELECT SLEEP(@SECONDS_TO_TEST);
```

to

```
SELECT SLEEP(@SECONDS_TO_TEST) INTO @abc;
```

for the raport to work.

Comment: This looks like a good contribution - improving an already accepted answer. However, it falls short of being an answer in its own right - I would make it a comment! It would be good if you could flag your own answer and ask the moderators to turn it into a comment. I'm giving it an upvote in the hope that you will be able to contribute more soon! :-) p.s. welcome to the forum - take the Tour, visit the Help Centre.